# Support vs "real" libraries and "classes could not be found"

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

When I try to use the RecyclerView in a test project when I'm about to try out Android 5.0 Lollipop, I see the following on Googles site:

[image]

1. What puzzles me is that they use the support thing instead of the "real" thing as provided in API 21. I was expecting to not use the support-package as I am running 5.0 on the device, have SDK 21 downloaded and installed. Why can't I just use RecyclerView directly, without using the support...?
2. Classes could not be found. In Android Studio, I get this error:

[image]

"Element RecyclerView is not allowed here" without further information. Also, if I use the example as posted above, I get the same error:

[image]

And if I click "Fix Build Path", I see:

[image]

I always have these problems using Java and Android, but the error messages are unclear. The path to the sdk is correct (under SDK Location).

This is  my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "se.snapcode.lollipoptest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

and this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="se.snapcode.lollipoptest" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I totally wrecked my first answer, let's try this again from the top...

> What puzzles me is that they use the support thing instead of the "real" thing as provided in API 21.

There is no "real" thing. `RecyclerView` is only in the Android Support package, via the `recyclerview-v7` library project/AAR.

This is akin to how Google packages `ViewPager` (`support-v4` and `support-v13`), `CardView` (`cardview-v7`), the Leanback UI for Android TV (`leanback-v17`), etc.

The Android Support libraries is not just a set of backports. It does include various classes that are only available via those libraries. In addition to the above, there is `NavUtils`, `FileProvider`, and various other classes that are "native" to the Android Support libraries.

So, if you want `RecyclerView`, add `recyclerview-v7` to your project, such as via Android Studio:

[image: Libraries Screenshot]

[image: Dependencies Screenshot]

or via your `app` module's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I see. How disappointing. I never liked those support libraries. So, to import them, you just add... what to gradle? If I go into the project properties, go to dependencies, click the plus-sign-->Library then I see a list with... stuff: 
support-v4, support-v13, appcompat-v7 and other stuff. Is it anyone of those? Appcompat-v7? Some gradle files writes: compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+' This doesnt make sense to me at all.

Comment: And, whats the difference between support-v4 and support-v13?

Comment: @Ted: "Is it anyone of those?" -- yes, see updated answer. "whats the difference between support-v4 and support-v13?" -- `support-v13` is a clear superset of `support-v4`, including some classes related to `ViewPager` that are only relevant for `minSdkVersion` of 13 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for the update. My next question is then: how would I know what to write in the gradle file? Cause that "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0" does not show up when I list libraries in the dependencies dialog, just "support-4" or "support-13" and some other irrelevant things... So, I can add so that Dependencies lists: "com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0" but nothing more specific than that.

Comment: @Ted: "Cause that "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0" does not show up when I list libraries in the dependencies dialog" -- check again, as that is how I added it. See the updated answer for another screenshot.

Comment: Forget it, I see it now. I must be blind =)