# UnsupportedOperationException - RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

So, after CommonsWare helped me out [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960670/support-vs-real-libraries-and-classes-could-not-be-found), I immediately ran into the next issue.

When adding a RecyclerView to a layout, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I immediately see:

[image]

My Gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "se.snapcode.lollipoptest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

and running Android Studio v 0.8.14.

I don't think this is the same issue as reported [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79623).

Also, when I run the app on my Nexus 5 (Android 5.0), I always get a NullRef, **but the app does not crash!**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler,
```

[image]

So, it says its a "fatal exception", but the app does not crash. I followed some of the instructions [on this site](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/), and my onCreate looks like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        // you can set the first visible item like this:
        layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }
```

So:

1. why does it give me a fatal exception?
2. why doesn't the app crash when I get the fatal exception?

Comment: Show up your LogCat log please.

Comment: maybe you try scrolltoPosition after create adapter